# How do I change size of truncatewords_html in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, responsive-design, responsive

I have used `truncatewords_html|90` for the truncate paragraphs. I want to change the size of truncatewords_html to 50 in mobile mode.
How do I do it?

`{{ student.description|safe|truncatewords_html:90  }}` in desktop mode

`{{ student.description|safe|truncatewords_html:50  }}` in mobile mode

Comment: How are you detecting "mobile mode"? Do you store the mode anywhere that you can access from your template/view?

Comment: No. I use the media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p id="myadata" class="card-text">

<script>   
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    desc1 = '{{pages.6.description|safe}}'
    let tmp1 = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp1.innerHTML = desc1;
    x1 =  tmp1.textContent || tmp1.innerText || "";

    if (w >= 1921){
        var truncated1 = x1.substring(0, 600);
        document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML=truncated1;
    }else if(w <=414){
        var truncated1 = x1.substring(60, length);
        document.getElementById('mydata').innerHTML=truncated1;
    }
</script>
```